# In javascript how will i convert 2016-05-21 20:00:00 to December 31 2016 00:00:50 UTC+0200

Tags: javascript

In javascript how will i convert `2016-05-21 20:00:00`  to `December 31 2016 00:00:50 UTC+0200`? I am a newbie so please forgive me if i appear to be naive.Please ignore the values.The format is what is confusing me.

Comment: the dates does not match.

Comment: What do you mean "convert"? They're completely different dates.

Comment: @nnnnnn I know what you mean but i have said that the values does not matter here in this context.The format is what is important here.

Comment: Sorry, your edit hadn't loaded in my browser even though you did it before I finished typing my comment. But wouldn't it have been easier to edit the values to match rather than adding a note to ignore the values?

Comment: @nnnnnn If i knew what would be the values i would have certainly done it.But being a complete newbie i dont even know what the values would had been.:) i could have changed the month day and year but i was confused about the time section.because there was utc+0200 shown there and i dont know what that word means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and the [ISO date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) as parameter

```js
document.write(new Date('2016-05-21 20:00:00'));
```

Comment: This works but instead of utc , ist and gmt is being shown in  my snippet.Can you please tell me if there is any workaround for this or this is alright

Comment: This is being shown in my snippet : Sat May 21 2016 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

Comment: it takes the local time.

Comment: you can change the format to [`2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) that produces zulu time

Comment: thank you for your reply.But you have provided me with the format that i needed.For now i dont need the zulu time format.